# Unable to find a class inside an imported module despite being able to import a different class from the same module

Tags: python, python-class

I'm using Python 3.9.6 and I'm learning about importing classes from a Python book. I've got a file with a couple of classes and one child class. I'm able to use `import car` and then access the `Car` class without any issues. But if I try to access the child class in the same file, `ElectricCar()`, I get an `ImportError`.

I don't think this can be a PATH problem since I'm able to access `Car` with no trouble. I'm following along with an example problem the author was able to do this so I'm trying to understand why it won't work for me.

This works:

```
from car import Car

myTesla = Car('tesla', 'model s', 2019)
```

But this does not:

```
from car import ElectricCar

myTesla = ElectricCar('tesla', 'model s', 2019)
```

I get this error when I try to import ElectricCar:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Marchy/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/Scripts/myElectricCar.py", line 1, in <module>
    from car import ElectricCar
ImportError: cannot import name 'ElectricCar' from 'car' (C:\Users/Marchy/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/Scripts\car.py)
```

This is the contents of `car.py` which contains both classes I'm trying to access:

```
'''A set of classes that can be used to represent gas and electric cars.'''

class Car:
    '''A simple attempt to represent a car.'''
    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        '''Initialize attributes to describe a car.'''
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
        self.odometer_reading = 0 # attribute with default value = 0

    def get_descriptive_name(self):
        '''Return a neatly formatted descriptive name.'''
        long_name = f'{self.year} {self.make} {self.model}'
        return long_name.title()

    
class Battery:
    '''A simple attempt to model a battery for an electric car.'''
    --snip--
            
class ElectricCar(Car):
    '''Represent aspects of a car, specific to electric vehicles.'''

    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        '''Initialize attributes of the parent class.
           Then initialize attributes specific to an electric car.
        '''
        super().__init__(make, model, year)
        self.battery = Battery()
```

Comment: My first guess would be a simple spelling error.  You have cut-and-pasted your sample, so we aren't seeing everything, but I'll wager the file has `Electriccar` or `ElectricCare` or `ElectrecCar`, or something similar.

Comment: Open a python shell in the directory. Do `import car`. Then do `dir(car)`. Post results.

Comment: The code you've posts works. There's something else wrong…

Answer (score 0):

Yikes, I've made a silly mistake. I had a separate file also named car.py that didn't include the ElectricCar class. When I imported car, I imported the version without ElectricCar.

Comment: In that case you should delete your entire question.

Comment: How did you have 2 files with the same name? Were you moving your scripts around different directories?

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted should work. Check if you have another file called `car.py` that does not have the `ElectricCar` class as you might have imported classes from that file.